# Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa. Проблема с Иксами

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xorg

После загрузки системы нет иконок на рабочем столе, а так же если открываю терминал, он открывается, но с таким багом.[image: ошибка терминала]

Также наблюдаются подвисания при попытке работы с "Менеджером обновлений", не открывает "Источники приложений".
Скорее всего, это произошло из-за добавления репозитория xorg и обновления драйвера на видео. Ничего более критичного не делал.

[image: пакеты synaptic[![пакеты synaptic2]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDRHx.png)

Comment: полностью снес все, что имеет слово xorg, перезагрузился, соответственно ничего не запустилось, с ошибкой иксов. все поставил заново, все загрузилось, ошибка осталась..

Comment: Та же проблема, только иногда выскакивает, помогало выходи вход в сеанс, или перезагрузка

Answer (score 1):

Ни один из советов, ни тут, ни на других сайтах не решил проблемы.
Но проблема была решена, полным удалением практически всего, что только можно.
Все, что имело отношение к Иксам, Cinnamon, MDM(Mint Display Manager), вместе с ними были удалены всякие сопутствующие пакеты и зависимости.
Потом был восстановлен дефолтный репозиторий Минта и все установлено Заново!
Все работает отлично!

Проблема, изначально, была после обновления ядра до 4.4.0-040400rc7-generic SMP Mon Dec 28 и установки ряда драйверов на видео. Каких точно, не знаю, потому что упали Иксы после перезагрузки, через пару дней.

Comment: Можно было не удалять cinnamon и mdm. Только иксы.

Comment: я пробовал по разному, и пробовал все по отдельности и группами. Не исключаю того, что когда удалял по отдельности, мог что то пропустить. Но именно полный снос под чистую всего, восстановление репозитория и установка с нуля решило проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
apt-get purge xorg*
apt-get install xorg
apt-get purge xserver*
apt-get install xserver*
```

Comment: Не помогло. Вот идентичная, по проблемам, ситуация. http://www.mintlinux.ru/forum/thread8859.html, но у меня нет драйверов nvidia.

Comment: тогда думаю проще переустановить польностью если нет опыта настройки иксов вручную. общий алгоритм, если не ошибаюсь:

Comment: тогда думаю проще переустановить польностью если нет опыта настройки иксов вручную. общий алгоритм, если не ошибаюсь: настройка X -> настройка Cinnamon -> установка драйвера видеокарты... для работы nvidia должно хватить пакета **xserver-xorg-video-nouveau**. какая точно наблюдается ошибка? ошибки иксов в /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: можно воспользоваться этим http://avreg.net/howto_x-org-server.html руководоством. сначала ставить голые иксы
# aptitude install xserver-xorg
или
# aptitude install x-window-system
для проверки 
$ startx.
затем драйвера nvidia
# aptitude install nvidia-kernel-dkms